# GWT. Set url without submit

Tags: gwt

Can i change url(set parameter) without submit?
I found this method
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#replace%28java.lang.String%29
but it submit page. All GWT state will be lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you trying to do this? Generally speaking, GWT apps don't change pages - thus they are normally **SPAs** (single page applications)

When you load a new page from a server, you will lose the state on that page. You can change the hash part of the URL as that won't return to the server, like this:

```
String newURL = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash("newhash").buildString();
Window.Location.replace(newURL);
```

However, if you're going to do this, I would recommend taking a look at GWT's MVP framework, which has built in support for managing locations using hash tokens.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

Comment: Thank you for useful answer. I need to change url without submit, so user can copy this and give to friend. For example wikimapia.org set in url current coordinates        http://wikimapia.org/#lat=54.3885546&lon=25.9799194&z=11&l=0&m=b

Comment: This helped my because I have a link that calls another GWT app.  I'm using Window.Location.assign()

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change something that is not in the hash, for example you want to change a parameter in the URL, you can do it like this!

```
private void someMethod() {
    String newURL = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setParameter("someParam", "someValue").buildString();
    updateURLWithoutReloading(newURL);
}

private static native void updateURLWithoutReloading(String newUrl) /*-{
    $wnd.history.pushState(newUrl, "", newUrl);
}-*/;
```

Then you could register a function that handles the user using the back and forward browser buttons as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page).

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, the one marked as correct causes a reload.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $wnd.history.pushState(newUrl, "", newUrl);
```

Works nicely in HTML5-browsers. Not in IE8 or IE9!