# how to jump to an anchor tag from a button clickhandler

Tags: gwt

I have a clickhandler for a button. I want the screen scrolls to an anchor like

```
Anchor a = new Anchor();
a.setName("stopHere");

(...)

button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Do somethings
            (...)

            // Scroll to Anchor "stopHere"

            ?????
}
});
```

How can I do it?

This is similar when using an anchor `<a href="#stopHere"> click to go to stopHere point </a>`, but I wan do it next the button is clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402732/gwt-set-url-without-submit help? I didn't try it but setting the hash token in the URL should do the trick I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`Element#scrollIntoView()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#scrollIntoView%28%29) should do what you want:

```
final Anchor a = new Anchor();
a.setName("stopHere");

button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        a.getElement().scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

Or use [`Window#scrollTo(int, int)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29)

```
final Anchor a = new Anchor();
a.setName("stopHere");

button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        Window.scrollTo(a.getAbsoluteLeft(), a.getAbsoluteTop());
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3347211 Excellent!