# Difference between button onclick and a href

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt, jsni

I'm trying to integrate SendOwl shopping cart into my application (details of the application are at the end).

To demo the problem I created a simple snippet using pure HTML / Javascript. In the head section of the HTML, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendOwl(url) {                 
        window.location.href=url;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://transactions.sendowl.com/assets/sendowl.js" ></script>
```

In the body I have this:

Example 1: Opens the checkout form in its own window (Undesired behavior):

```
<input type="button" onclick="SendOwl('https://transactions.sendowl.com/products/8/5C080C0F/purchase');" value="On Click" />
```

Screenshot 1: Notice the URL changed and it's not an overlay (compared to 2).

[image]

Example 2: Opens the checkout form in a modal window as an overlay (Desired behavior):

```
<a href='https://transactions.sendowl.com/products/8/5C080C0F/purchase'>a href</a>
```

Screenshot 2: The URL stays the same, but the form opens in an overlay.

[image]

You can also see a live demo on the SendOwl's demo page.

My application is based on GWT (SmartGWT to be precise). In my application, I call button onclick handler to invoke a Javascript that invokes the Buy Now link using JSNI call (shown below). But the Buy Now link always opens in a full window as in example 1 above.

```
public static native void onBuyNowClick(String url) /*-{
  $wnd.SendOwl(url);
}-*/;
```

I have tried `$wnd.open(url)` but that has the same behavior.

How do I get the first example to behave like the second but still using button onclick?

**UPDATE:**

The magic is in the sendowl.js script. If I remove that script, then both examples work the same way. If I could figure out how that script works, it might give some clues to make Example 1 work the same way as Example 2.

Thanks.

Comment: to open classic href in a new window you can use `target= "_blank"`

Comment: That's not the issue here. I know how to open a link in a new window. The href example (#2) is the desired behavior. The requirement is to stay in the same window and show the checkout form in an overlay on the current window. If I may request you to head over to the SendOwl demo page (https://www.sendowl.com/demo) and click on Credit Card Demo button to see how it works. Hope that would make the requirement more clear.

Comment: I added answer, that may help you

Comment: wait, i will edit my answer

Comment: Hi all! I just wanted to ask, how does GWT doing now? Can I start a new project using it or it becomes deprecated?

Comment: @KaPaHgaIII I think you should post a new question for that. It doesn't belong to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue myself by probing into the sendowl.js . That's the script which is doing all the magic.

This is my modified script that makes Example 1 work exactly like Example 2:

```
<script>
    function SendOwl(url) { 
        sendOwl.addLoadingImage();
        sendOwl.loadIframe ('https://transactions.sendowl.com/products/8/5C080C0F/purchase');
    }
</script>
<script src="https://transactions.sendowl.com/assets/sendowl.js"></script>
```

Thanks to all who replied and tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://transactions.sendowl.com/assets/sendowl.js" ></script>
<a href="https://transactions.sendowl.com/products/8/5C080C0F/purchase" rel="nofollow"><input type="button" value="Purchase" /></a>
```

https://help.sendowl.com/help/article/link/button-codes-to-sell-your-product

Works fine for me.
[image]

Comment: Actually I've tried that approach already. It makes no difference. The form just displays in the same window but not as an overlay as it does in Example 2 and also on the sendowl demo page, which I have linked to in my comments above. I'll add couple of screenshots to show the problem. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @DFB figured this out, i will post answer now

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle and I think you are still not getting the issue. The a href example is working fine without rel="nofollow" and target="_blank". I'm asking why onclick (Example 1) is not working the same way. I need to use button onclick in my application. I can't use <a href='...' > there. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: rel='nofollow' has nothing to do with this issue as far as I know. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @DFB I will send you a screenshot, it wont work on jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104953/discussion-between-nikolapro-and-dfb).

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't work on jsfiddle either way. But if you create a simple HTML page on your local machine and open it in a browser you can see the issue. The code you have posted still uses 'a href'. I need to make it work with onclick javascript function.

Comment: @DFB i think there i s no way to do that, even SendOwl site use only <a> and css (class). you can create that a looks like a button, so only way to do it is with <a> because javascript will change location.

Comment: It's not about the button look. But inside SmartGWT even a href links behave like the onclick example. I'm trying to figure out a way to make it work in an overlay. Thanks again.

Comment: @DFB I don't know then :/

Answer (score 0):

In GWT you can use a [PopupPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) to display the overlay. Personally I never tried embedding a page inside a popup but you can try adding a [Frame](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) object inside the popup panel, something like this:

```
PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel();
Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.yourlink.com/");
popup.setWidget(frame);
popup.setGlassEnabled(true);
popup.center();
```

As for the URL please check the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402732/gwt-set-url-without-submit)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have tried this approach in SmartGWT and it works to some extent but with some glitches. I used the modal Window of SGWT which is a similar widget to what you proposed. Some actions inside the checkout form result in javascript error when running inside the SGWT's modal Window. I have to go with that approach anyway if I don't find a cleaner solution. I'm really trying to understand the difference in my Example 1 and 2 in pure HTML/Javascript terms keeping GWT aside.